# Use comma within PHP statement only if needed

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom theme for WordPress and have what is probably the silliest issue with a comma!  I'm using the following code to present entry-meta:

```
<?php
                    printf( __( '<span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author screenreader">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s" pubdate>%3$s</time></a> <span class="meta-sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" title="%5$s">%6$s, %7$s</a></span>', 'ngngcustom' ),
                        get_permalink(),
                        get_the_date( 'c' ),
                        get_the_date(),
                        get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
                        sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'ngngcustom' ), get_the_author() ),
                        get_the_author(),
                        get_the_author_meta('user_title')
                    );
                ?>
```

The problem is that not all users will have a title.  How do I get rid of the hanging comma (between %6$s and %7$s) in those instances?  Please realize I don't know php.  I just copy / paste and tweak it a bit. So I really need a clear solution.

Comment: what title? can you be more clear please?
 what does the 6 & 7 means ?

Comment: I think this is the title referred to: `<a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" title="%5$s">%6$s, %7$s</a>`

Comment: Please realize that *Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it*. So a question that is essentially "plz write this code for me" may not be the best fit.

Comment: I don't know how thems in WP are implemented, but I think `printf` is not needed here

Comment: Really?  I'm pretty sure I wasn't asking anyone to write the code for me.  I managed to make it this far and just need help understanding what I did wrong.  Professional and enthusiastic programmers don't shut professional and enthusiastic newbies under the bus!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Get rid of the comma in your `printf` and add this code:

```
$author_title = get_the_author_meta('user_title');
if (0 < strlen($author_title)) {
  $author_title = ', '.$author_title;
} else {
  $author_title = '';
}
printf( __( '<span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author screenreader">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s" pubdate>%3$s</time></a> <span class="meta-sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" title="%5$s">%6$s %7$s</a></span>', 'ngngcustom' ),
                    get_permalink(),
                    get_the_date( 'c' ),
                    get_the_date(),
                    get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
                    sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'ngngcustom' ), get_the_author() ),
                    get_the_author(),
                    $author_title
                );
?>
```

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much.  You have no idea how many hours I've spent trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you can move the comma to the parameter and use an inline condition to check if it's empty or not. Something like this. Although I'm not sure if this works at all. Worth giving it a try.

```
<?php
                    printf( __( '<span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author screenreader">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s" pubdate>%3$s</time></a> <span class="meta-sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" title="%5$s">%6$s %7$s</a></span>', 'ngngcustom' ),
                        get_permalink(),
                        get_the_date( 'c' ),
                        get_the_date(),
                        get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
                        sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'ngngcustom' ), get_the_author() ),
                        get_the_author(),
                        ((get_the_author_meta('user_title') != '') ? ', '.get_the_author_meta('user_title') : '')
                    );
                ?>
```

Comment: I tried something very similar to this with no luck.... but thanks for trying to point me in the right direction.